# Trouble running my code: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0

Tags: android, loops, arraylist, libgdx, indexoutofboundsexception

can someone help me out with this problem.  this is the error message I get:

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:635)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:411)
    at com.mygdx.Papermadness.Papermadness.render(Papermadness.java:102)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:206)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:114)
```

This is the code of my for loop through the huisArray (huis= house).

```
private ArrayList<Sprite> huisArray = new ArrayList<Sprite>();

spriteBatch.begin();

    sprite.draw(spriteBatch);



     for (int i = 0; i < huisArray.size(); i++) {
            huisArray.get(i).setY(huisArray.get(i).getY() - huisVelocity * delta);

                 if (huisArray.get(i).getY() <= 200) {
                huisArray.remove(huisArray.get(i));
            } 

        }


      if (huisArray.get(0).getY() < 1200) {
            addNewHuis();
        }

     huisBatch.begin();

     for (int i = 0; i < huisArray.size(); i++) {
            huisArray.get(i).setY(huisArray.get(i).getY() - huisVelocity * delta);

                 if (huisArray.get(i).getY() <= 200) {
                huisArray.remove(huisArray.get(i));
            } 

        }


      if (huisArray.get(0).getY() < 1200) {
            addNewHuis();
        }

     huisBatch.begin();


      for (int i = 0; i < huisArray.size(); i++) {
            huisBatch.draw(huisArray.get(i), huisArray.get(i).getX(), huisArray.get(i).getY());
        }
spriteBatch.end();
    huisBatch.end();
```

The idea of this code is that houses at the two edges of the screen fall continuesly.

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Where do you add elements to `huisArray ` and which line is 102?

Comment: post your entire stacktrace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `huisArray` is empty and you are getting values from this list at line

```
  if (huisArray.get(0).getY() < 1200) {
```

So first add items in `huisArray` before checking item  in  `huisArray` as

```
private ArrayList<Sprite> huisArray = new ArrayList<Sprite>();
// Add huisArray item here as huisArray.add(addspritehere);
```

Or change

```
  if (huisArray.get(0).getY() < 1200) {
```

to

```
if (huisArray.size() > 0 && huisArray.get(0).getY() < 1200) {
```

Comment: Thank you. Now my program runs but it doesnt draw houses. Could you check where it goes wrong if I edit the question to show my full code?

Comment: Did you add some sprites values in  huisArray ?

Comment: @user3091110 Ask a new question.  If this answer answered this question, accept it and upvote it.

Answer (score 1):

Your error is likely right here:

```
if (huisArray.get(0).getY() < 1200) {
```

If your `huisArray` has a size of zero, then getting an object out of it will throw an exception.  You should check if it has anything in it first, as follows

```
if (huisArray.size() > 0 && huisArray.get(0).getY() < 1200) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
if (huisArray.get(0).getY() < 1200) {
        addNewHuis();
    }
```

You're accessing to the first element in the huisArray, but never checking if it's empty.

Add a size check before:

```
if (huisArray.size > 0 &&huisArray.get(0).getY() < 1200) {
        addNewHuis();
    }
```

There's also another problem in your for loops:

```
for (int i = 0; i < huisArray.size(); i++) {
        huisArray.get(i).setY(huisArray.get(i).getY() - huisVelocity * delta);

             if (huisArray.get(i).getY() <= 200) {
            huisArray.remove(huisArray.get(i));
        } 

    }
```

If you remove things inside the for loop just like that, you'll be ignoring some items:

Let's say you're array have 3 elements [A, B, C], and the first one have the conditions to be removed.

So in the first loop, you'll have:

i = 0
array = [A, B, C]

A is removed, and the second loop starts

i = 1
array = [B, C]

See that now you'll check for C (which is in position 1), and you'll never check B

To avoid this (using that kind of for loop) just add:

```
for (int i = 0; i < huisArray.size(); i++) {
        huisArray.get(i).setY(huisArray.get(i).getY() - huisVelocity * delta);

             if (huisArray.get(i).getY() <= 200) {
            huisArray.remove(huisArray.get(i));
            i--;
        } 

    }
```

Also as an advice, if you know the position of the item you wan't to remove, remove it by index instead of removing by object (it's faster)

```
huisArray.remove(i);
```